# Google Chrome desktop browser keeps "pausing" sign in

Tags: google-chrome, login

Google Chrome desktop browser keeps "pausing" sign in. (see screenshot below)

Which in turn logs me out of websites that i use "sign in with google" on. In order to get it working again i click "paused" and re log in.

Is there a way to stop Google Chrome desktop browser "pausing" the sign in.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

There have been reports that breaking the link between the Google Account
in Chrome that is used to sync data and Google accounts on Internet sites
may solve this problem:

- In Chrome, enter `chrome://flags/#account-consistency` in the address bar
- The flag "Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar" should be displayed
  at the top all in yellow
- Click the drop-down button and set it to "Disabled"
- Restart Chrome

If that doesn't help, disabling the sign-in and out link between Chrome
and other Google services might also help:

- Navigate in Chrome to `chrome://flags`
- At the bottom of the page click *Advanced*
- Under "Privacy and security", toggle "Allow Chrome sign-in" so it becomes grey
- Restart Chrome

For more information see the ghacks article
[Disable the sign-out link between Chrome, Gmail and other Google services](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/09/08/disable-the-sign-out-link-between-chrome-gmail-and-other-google-services/).

Comment: appolgoies, i havnt had access to the computer the issue was occuring on for a few days should be back with it next week

Comment: Unfortunately, due to unforeseen circumstances, yes

Comment: neither of these suggestions solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

If you have browser history set to clear everytime you completely close out of Chrome, that will cause it. You can change the behavior by going to Settings --> Advanced Settings --> Content Settings --> Cookies --> Uncheck "Keep local data until you quit browser"