# How to stop Google Chrome "pausing" when I log in on another machine

Tags: google-chrome

(This question is more specific than [Google Chrome desktop browser keeps "pausing" sign in](https://superuser.com/q/1425603/119532) , and the answers provided there don't help in this case)

I have two desktop devices (macbooks).  Quite reproducibly, I can only be logged into Google Chrome on one of them.     When I "unpause" one, then go do the other (located in a different place) it is "paused".    If I unpause that and return to the former, it is paused.

I don't even appear to have the "Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar" flag mentioned in the other question.

Comment: Have you turned off Google Chrome Sync ?   Settings, Sync and Google services. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I'll explore that.  It's a pretty hefty chunk of functionality to turn off though...

Comment: It appears that this cures the problem, but it's basically saying "you can't use sync unless you log into each device every time you change device".  Surely that can't be how sync works?

Comment: You may need to adapt to  the pause - I am not sure what else at this point.

Comment: It appears that removing sync removes the problem.    But is this the common experience, or something special about my circumstance?   Given that the whole premise of sync is same-user-multiple-devices, it seems bizarre that it causes pause for everyone without that being questioned...